# Why doesn't this CSS :first-child selector work?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm working on an Asp.Net MVC 3 project and have run into a brick wall on why this doesn't work like I think it should.

My markup is:

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" value="2">
    <div class="editor-label"> 
        <label for="Name"> Name</label>
    </div>
    ...
</fieldset>
```

My css is:

```
.display-label, .editor-label
{
    margin: 0.8em 0 0 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
}

fieldset > div:first-child
{
    margin: 0;
}
```

All I want to do is make the first div in the fieldset have a margin of 0. I thought that the selector `fieldset > div:first-child` would apply the style to "the first child of a fieldset, whose type is a div", but apparently something is eluding me.

I've tried this in IE9/FF/Chrome so it's not an old browser messing with my selectors.

Thanks.

Comment: try fieldset > div.editor-label:first-child{margin-top:0}

Comment: seems to work here http://jsfiddle.net/VcRyL/ check your css see if there isn't a property rule overriding this rule

Comment: @AndreDublin that doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/5dAKL/1

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`fieldset > div:first-child` means "select the first child element of a `fieldset` *if* it's a `div`".

It does not mean "select the first `div` in the `fieldset`".

The first child in this case is `<input type="hidden" value="2">`.

To select that `div` without changing the HTML, you need to use `fieldset > div:first-of-type`.

Unfortunately, while [`:first-child`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild) is widely supported, [`:first-of-type`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstoftype) only works in  IE9+ and other modern browsers.

So, in this case, the best fix is to continue using `fieldset > div:first-child`, and simply move `<input type="hidden" value="2">` so that's it's not the first child.

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense.  I didn't know that the `> div:first-child` also meant "_IF_ it's a div", I just thought that it always selected the first matching child.  I will have to rearrange the markup because my client is stuck on IE8 for now.

Thanks!