# CSS selector to hide first of a set

Tags: css, css-selectors

To start, I have no control over the html. I am looking for a CSS solution. CSS2/3 are fine. I have no idea why I can't figure this out, but hey it's Friday. I guess my brain is scrambled.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/PDBmU/13/

I need to hide the span.smalltext containing (Documentation x.x.x). In the fiddle I highlighted this with a red box.

```
<div class="result">                       
  <span class="icon icon-page" title="Page">Page:</span>
  <a href="/display/">Create</a>
  <!-- Hide this span -->
  <span class="smalltext" style="border: 1px solid red;">
    (<a href="/display/doc">Documentation x.x.x</a>)
  </span>    
  <br>
    ... <span class="search-highlight"><strong>search</strong></span> project ...         
  <br>
  <span class="smalltext">    
    Jun 17, 2011 14:57
  </span>
</div>
<!-- ## The above structure is repeated many times. I would like to hide all of them.  -->
```

I tried something like this so far - but it didn't work

```
div.result span.smalltext:first-child {display: none;}
```

Comment: are you trying to hide it permanently or for it to reshow after an event?

Comment: I am just going to hide it from my stylesheet. I just need the correct selector. Something like `div.result span.smalltext:first-child {display: none;}`. I also just realized I forgot an important aspect which is that there are multiple search results on the page. I will update my answer.

Comment: do you have jQuery available? In this case it is: `$('.smalltext:first').css('background-color', 'red');`

Comment: @Sam - sorry I didn't have in my original question that there are multiple of these. See how your solution only gets first box - http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/PDBmU/18/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could...

```
.result a + .smalltext {
    display:none;
}
```

... do it? I also made a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8AzcB/1/)

Comment: Both your answer and Joseph's are good. However, I think I will go with this one as the sibling selector has slightly better support than the nth-of-type selector

Answer (score 2):

```
.result span:nth-of-type(2) {display:none}
```

[works too](http://jsfiddle.net/yTX3q/)... albeit messy like :P

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen True.  it would probably be a better practice to be explicit.

Answer (score 2):

> I just need the correct selector.
>   Something like `div.result
>   span.smalltext:first-child {display: none;}`

See this answer for why your attempt did not work: [Why doesn't this CSS :first-child selector work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589841/why-doesnt-this-css-first-child-selector-work/7589895#7589895)

Use `.result > span:first-child + a + .smalltext` instead.

This selector will work in all browsers (except IE6).

Comment: I thought I knew CSS pretty well. I think I need to look at advanced selector syntax again, haha.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation link. It is important to understand WHY things work!

Answer (score 1):

Two different approaches I'd say, either CSS or jQuery
CSS:

```
.result span:nth-of-type(2) {font-weight:bold;}
```

JS:

```
$('.result').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.smalltext:first').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

That's as long as the HTML really doesn't change. Fiddle'd it, too http://jsfiddle.net/PDBmU/19/

/edit
Obviously the css attributes given in this example are for demonstration purpose, you'd need display:none; or display:hidden; depending on wanted output

Comment: Thanks for the jQuery solution. I also like that. Will stick with CSS for now, but it is nice to have a js backup solution.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure, how stable this is, as your output could contain a lot of `a + span`s, but this should work with your example

```
.result > a + span {
  display: none;
}
```